# IS the composition of infinite APF extensions again APF?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-fields

Convention: By APF extension, I mean APF extension of $\mathbb{Q_p}$.

For $\mathbb{Q_p} \subseteq L_1 \subseteq L_2$ where $L_2/L_1$ is finite, we know that $L_1/\mathbb{Q_p}$ is APF iff $L_2/\mathbb{Q_p}$ is APF. With this in mind, I have two questions:

1-Is the composition of a finitely many infinite APF extensions again APF?

2-What about infinite compositions of infinite APF extensions?

Comment: APF =  arithmetically profinite